# What Raid should I use for Website Static Files / Content

Tags: iis, web-server, raid, hard-drive, ssd

I'm building a Web server (IIS7) and would like to know the best practice for storing static content and the uploaded files of website's users (predominantly pictures, but also other documents like pdf's). I will keep the operating System on a Raid 1 array.

Where should I be keeping the actual website's pages & files, it's own static content, and that of it's users?

- Should I be placing this content on a seperate raid array, and if so which type?

I was considering using SLC SSD's (Such as the Intel's X25-e) but the following issues came to light.

- Will the SLC SSD's give any improvement over a 2.5" 15k SAS Drive for this type of content?
- If I did use SSD's, I'm under the belief I would still need to use Raid for redundancy, yet I've heard Intel X25-e's don't support TRIM. Does this scrap them as a legitimate option?

Comment: Are you looking for performance or redundancy or a mix of both for your static content?

Comment: Performance, allowing fast page loads for end users, and yes, redundancy incase a drive fails.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would be looking into what RAID is and which types offer me the best setup for my storage.

That being said, with only the information you gave, I would use the money you would spend on the SSD you could easily build a four drive RAID 5 array. Look into that and see if the downsides would affect your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Raid 1. Mirror. Because basicaly you dont have anything worth a larger arra anyway. Use output caching as needed.

If that would not b enough space wise, then RAID 5 with a good controller. Raid 5 is slow for writes, but good for reads. Not as good as Raid 10, but then it is.... cheaper.

Again, a good controller may help a lot. Adapte allows you to plug in a set of SSD's (up to 4) as active read caches (i.e. the controller puts often requested stuff there for faster reads).